# Opencl math New to opencl trying to convert octave to opencl or c getting different results

Tags: c, math, opencl, octave

I just need a little help converting these lines of octave to opencl i guess i'm confused on the translation ^ to pow her is octave/opencl code but the results are not the same

```
v1=0.3; 
E1=(207*(10^9)); 
E2=(3*(10^6)); 
v2=0.49;
```

**octave**

```
Ers=1/(1/pi*((1-v1^2)/E1+(1-v2^2)/E2));%MPa  Whats this look like in c
DEF=(6*n*U*B^2)/Er/(sigma^3);
```

**my opencl attempt at translation**

Ers=(1.00/(1.00/pi*((1.00-pow(v1 ,2))/E1+(1.00-pow(v2, 2))/E2)));           //MPa
   DEF=6*n*U*pow(B,2)/Er/pow(sigma,3);

octave results
//ers 1.2402e+07
//DEF 30.962

opencl results
Ers 139.336666
DEF -0.000003

not sure what i've done wrong but if someone sees it please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL is derived from C99, so you can check your conversion is correct with a trivial vanilla C program.

If I take your C version of the `Ers` calculation and run it with C, the result I get matches your Octave result. I suspect your issue lies in the definition of your `E1` and `E2` constant values. If I paste those into the C program unchanged, I get an answer very similar to your OpenCL result. The issue is that although `10^9` is syntactically valid in C, it doesn't mean the same as in Octave (`^` is the bitwise XOR operator in C). Instead, you should use scientific E notation, such as  `1e9`.

So, here's a complete C program that computes the `Ers` value using your C code copied almost verbatim, with just the constant values corrected. This produces the output `Ers = 1.24024e+07` on my system.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double v1 = 0.3;
  double E1 = (207*(1e9));
  double E2 = (3*(1e6));
  double v2 = 0.49;
  double pi = M_PI;
  double Ers = (1.00/(1.00/pi*((1.00-pow(v1,2))/E1+(1.00-pow(v2, 2))/E2)));
  printf("Ers = %g\n", Ers);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much very right so let me get this straight in c to transpose 10^-7 would be 1e-7? that works woot thanks thanks